# Add a column to an existing database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, view

I am using rails 3.1.3, postgreql9.1 and ruby 1.9.3.

I would like to add a column to an existing database that is really the concatenation of two existing columns, namely; first_name and last_name.

How does one go about doing this?

The reason I want the fullname is that when it comes time to display the employees, I would like to just show the fullname, but I need the name split up into two parts for other functions.

Also part of this question is that while I only want the fullname of the employee to show on a report, I would also like the employees email and primary position to show and then to have a link, called info, which when clicked will give a detailed report on the employee showing all the attributes in the employee table.

So far, I have a rudimentary employee page.

Any reader have the patience and willingness to share some pointers, guidance and or advice on how to go about this task?

Thanks,

Tom.

Comment: select first_name || ' ' || last_name as fullname from... -  this will concatenate the first and last name in a query...any reason you'd want to store the full name when it can reproduced in a query this easily?  || (pipe symbol) is the quick way of concatenating in postgres (you'll notice I put a space between first and last names using this).  You could throw a middle initial or the sort in there too using the same logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create the real field in your database you can use [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

But in this case you can use virtiual attributes:

Create two methods in your model:

```
def full_name
   [first_name, last_name].joun(' ')
end

def full_name=(name)
    split = name.split(' ', 2)
    self.first_name = split.first
    self.last_name = split.last
end
```

And add to your view:

```
<p> Full name </p>  
<%= f.text_field :full_name %>
```

Comment: Thank-you tewlfth, zed_oxff, jamesTheprogrammer and @demas, lots of good stuff you have all given me...I get the argument of not adding to the db and will follow that advice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just concatenate the names in your views?

There is no real need to duplicate DB data such way.

Answer (score 0):

While you could solve this problem without editing the db structure as suggested, you could create a new db col and may need to edit the db structure in the future.

Try this page, admin tools for your db type
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration.

This one looks like a good fit.

pgAdmin

"The pgAdmin pakage is a free and open source graphical user interface administration tool for PostgreSQL, which is supported on many computer platforms".

Fish for a man, he eats for a day. Teach a man to fish, he eats for a lifetime.